# SAML Idp Creation taking too much time

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, adfs, kentor-authservices, sustainsys-saml2

I am using "**Kentor.AuthServices.dll**" and **"Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc.dll"** in my code to allowing Single sign on with ADFS server and it is working fine but the problem is that it is taking around more than 1 min show the adfs login screen.

I have debugged the code and record the timing and found the all the code working fine but **identity provider** creating code is taking more than 1 min.

I am not able to understand why it is taking too much time.

I am putting my code below can anyone please help?

thanks in advance.

```
try
    {
    CommonUtility.LogMessage("Start at:" + DateTime.Now);
    string adfsUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServer"] ?? "";
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(adfsUrl))
    {
    CommonUtility.LogMessage("no adfs server found in config");
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", string.Empty);
    }

        string requestUrlScheme = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADInstance"] ?? "https";
        string federationUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADFSMetaData"] ?? "";

        CommonUtility.LogMessage("metdaDataUrl=" + federationUrl);

        string trustUrl = string.Format("{0}/adfs/services/trust", adfsUrl);

        CommonUtility.LogMessage("trustURL=" + trustUrl);

        var idps = Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc.AuthServicesController.Options.IdentityProviders.KnownIdentityProviders;
        foreach (var idpItem in idps)
        {
            CommonUtility.LogMessage("existing ENtity ID=" + idpItem.EntityId.Id);
            if (idpItem.EntityId.Id.Equals(trustUrl))
            {
                Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc.AuthServicesController.Options.IdentityProviders.Remove(idpItem.EntityId);
                CommonUtility.LogMessage("removed existing entity at:" + DateTime.Now);
            }
        }

        var spOptions = CreateSPOptions(requestUrlScheme);

        CommonUtility.LogMessage("SP option created at:" + DateTime.Now);

        Kentor.AuthServices.IdentityProvider idp = null;


        **idp = new Kentor.AuthServices.IdentityProvider(new EntityId(trustUrl), spOptions)
        {
            AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
            LoadMetadata = true,
            MetadataLocation = federationUrl,

        };**
        CommonUtility.LogMessage("idp added at:" + DateTime.Now);
        if (Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc.AuthServicesController.Options.SPOptions.EntityId == null)
            Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc.AuthServicesController.Options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId(string.Concat(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", requestUrlScheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~")), "AuthServices"));
        else
            Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc.AuthServicesController.Options.SPOptions.EntityId.Id =
                      string.Concat(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", requestUrlScheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~")), "AuthServices");


        CommonUtility.LogMessage("AuthServicesURL=" + string.Concat(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", requestUrlScheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~")), "AuthServices"));

        Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc.AuthServicesController.Options.SPOptions.ReturnUrl =
            new Uri(string.Concat(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", requestUrlScheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~")), "SAMLAuthentication/SAMLResponse"));

        CommonUtility.LogMessage("SAMLResponseURL=" + string.Concat(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", requestUrlScheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~")), "SAMLAuthentication/SAMLResponse"));


        Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc.AuthServicesController.Options.IdentityProviders.Add(idp);
        CommonUtility.LogMessage("redirect times:" + DateTime.Now);
        return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "AuthServices", new { idp = trustUrl });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CommonUtility.LogException(ex);
        throw ex;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use "LoadMetadata", the IdentityProvider object will load the metadata from the remote address at construction time. If I remember correctly, that's done synchronously to be able to report errors back as an exception. Does it take time (or give a timeout) to download the metadata?

Comment: Thanks, @Anders for your reply. if I download the metadata from remote location in the browser it will not take more than 2-3 seconds. but in the code, it takes more than 1 min to complete the new idp creation. I have also tried to use the metadata file from the local folder(downloaded metadata). but it is taking the same time as it takes with a remote location. Thanks

Comment: Looks like some debugging is needed. Can you please mail me the metadata file at anders@sustainsys.com?

Comment: I have sent you the metadata file. please let me the problem. Thanks!